# why my database updated value not shown on report viewer?

Tags: c#, ado.net

In my application when i click on submit button all values are inserted into database.

For printing these currently inserted value i am using report viewer on another form.

There are 2 buttons submit and print .submit button gives me last value's unique id and this id's detail i want to print on report.but when i click on print button i does not print any data.

i have already tried but on clicking print button it does not show any data on report viewer.
How can i fetch my current values on click of my print button. I tried but it does not not work on current values.

```
           int id = Convert.ToInt32(Form1.lblbillno1);
        this.Customer_detailTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.Customer_detail,id);             
         this.Bill_DetailTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet2.Bill_Detail,id);
         reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
         this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport
```

Comment: please share your C# code.whatever you have tried.So someone can get some idea about your problem.

Comment: int id = Convert.ToInt32(Form1.lblbillno1);

             this.Customer_detailTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.Customer_detail,id);
             
             this.Bill_DetailTableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet2.Bill_Detail,id);
             reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
             this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport

Comment: Don't share the code in comment.Click on edit link and update your question.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the same problem. I was searching for a few days in internet but I couldn't find a good answer for it. So I hope my post will help somebody to overcome the same problem.

All you need to do - just define manually the connection, refill the dataset and bind the source to reportviewer. Here is my project example:

```
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;


    private void ReportForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\GD Robotics\VisualProjects\GDPolin\GDPolin\PolinaDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter reportDBTableAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM  [ReportDB]", conn);
        DataTable polinaDBDataSet = new DataTable();
        reportDBTableAdapter.Fill(polinaDBDataSet);
        conn.Close();

        this.reportViewer1.Reset();
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"D:\GD Robotics\VisualProjects\GDPolin\GDPolin\Report1.rdlc";
        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", polinaDBDataSet);//"DataSet1" is the name of your dataset. Go to .rdlc form>VIEW>Report Data>"Right click on dataset">Dataset Properties
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```